# How to replace a character with another character by character code

Tags: substitute, unicode

I want to write a command that replaces all of a line's spaces with [figure spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_space), and I want the code to not use those literal characters so it is more legible than `:s/ / /g`

So, naturally, I try various iterations like:

```
:s/\x20/\u2007/g      " matches a hex char then "20", adds uppercase "2007"
:s/\%u20/\%u2007/g
:s/[\x20]/\\%u2007/g
:s/[\x20]/^Vu2007/g                " that's a literal <Ctrl-V>
:s/\%u20/\=printf("%c", 0x2007)/g  " gives me ^G instead
:s/\%u20/\="\<Char-0x2007>"/g      " gives me <e2><80><fe>X<87> instead
```

None of these work, though all of the patterns do indeed match spaces.

I see lots of tricks around for how to enter Unicode characters in Insert mode, but none about how to do so in a replacement string.

In researching this question, I found [How to translate Unicode escape sequences to the Unicode character](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/how-to-translate-unicode-escape-sequences-to-the-unicode-character), which gives me the following functional solution:

```
:s/\%u20/\=nr2char(0x2007)/g
```

Is there really no cleaner way to do this?  I assume that's unnecessarily costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you didn't see an error message telling you that there was no match.  Your problem is `\x20` which was matching nothing.  Your pattern was effectively:

```
[0-9A-Fa-f]20
```

`\x` matches a hex digit atom.  See `:h /\x`.  What you're thinking of are string special characters (`:h expr-quote`), which aren't expanded in patterns.

This is what you want:

```
execute ":s/ /\u2007/g"

or

:s/ /\="\u2007"/g

or

:s/\%u20/\="\u2007"/g
```

Just use a literal space as the pattern.

Comment: That was a typo; `/[\x20]/` works.  I'll adjust the question.  This is still "executing" `"\u2007"` though, isn't it?  Wouldn't that therefore have a (admittedly very small) extra cost beyond a literal figure space?

Comment: Are you talking about performance cost? Vim's script is literally the same as you typing it in the command line. There's no bytecode cache--it's always "executed". So yes, `\="\u2007"` evaluates a string and returns it during execution before substitution. It's also the simplest way for you to have an opaque representation of that character.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.