# Search and replace unicode character codes with actual characters

Tags: unicode, ascii

I've got a text file with unicode character codes in it. It looks like this in vim (`utf-8[unix]`):

```
Samuel i<81>ngel - Euro <80>25
Tomas i<81>lvaro - ©Coca-Cola and dagger <87>
Luis i<81>lvaro
Scooter ð<9d><90>ƒð<9d><90>²ð<9d><90>¥ð<9d><90>šð<9d><90>§
```

When I use `less` to view it I get this:

```
Samuel i<U+0081>ngel - Euro <U+0080>25
Tomas i<U+0081>lvaro - ©Coca-Cola and dagger <U+0087>
Luis i<U+0081>lvaro
Scooter ð<U+009D><U+0090>ƒð<U+009D><U+0090>²ð<U+009D><U+0090>¥ð<U+009D><U+0090>šð<U+009D><U+0090>§
```

I've been trying to replace *all* the hex character codes in the file with their unicode characters using `nr2char` and `submatch`, but I can't get it to work with *all* of them in one search/replace. Can anyone help? It works to replace a single one (e.g. `<90>` with :

`:1,$ s/\%\(\%x90\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g`

I cannot extend this to all of them though - I've tried things like the following:

```
:1,$ s/\([\%x00-\%xFF]\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g <== replaces loads of characters
:1,$ s/\%\(\%x[80-90]\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g <== Invalid character after \%[dxouU]
:1,$ s/\%\([\x80-\xFF]\{2\}\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g <== only replaces <9D>
:1,$ s/\%\([\x80-\xFF]\{2\}\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1))/g <== only removes <9D>
:1,$ s/\%\([\x80-\xFF]\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(0))/g <== removes all, does not replace
:1,$ s/\(\%[\x80-\xFF]\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g <== does weird random stuff with new lines
[...]
```

(I appreciate this is close to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/how-to-translate-unicode-escape-sequences-to-the-unicode-character), but it's not exactly the same)

Comment: Can you tell us by what you would like to replace `<90>`? Is it by `"0x90"`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt good question, thanks. With `<90>` I just looked it up and it's officially unused. But certainly I'd like to replace the `<80>` with € and the `<87>` with ‡.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that Vim not opening the file using the right encoding. Your file is in encoding `cp1252` but Vim doesn't detect it and guess `utf-8`.

I would propose to open the file with the `++enc=cp1252` flag.

```
:e ++enc=cp1252 filepath
```

To improve the way Vim guess the encoding you can add the following lines (Vim would first try to open as `cp1252` and then as `utf-8`):

```
:set fileencodings=cp1252,utf-8
```

Comment: Hi @Sam if the solution solves your problem I'll be glad if you could accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Thanks Vivian! It's nearly there, but interestingly setting the encoding above gives me a little Â in front of everything - e.g. `Euro Â€25` - any idea why?

Comment: I should have a look to your file. Could you share an extract?

Comment: It would also help to get a screenshot and the list of Vim operation that lead to that screenshot together with the result of the following command `:set fileencoding?`

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you:

```
:s/\([\x80-\xFF]\)/\='0x'.printf('%02x', char2nr(submatch(1)))/g
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work on search (great!), but the replace gives me this:

`Samuel i0x81ngel - Euro 0x8025
Tomas i0x81lvaro - 0xa9Coca-Cola and dagger 0x87
Luis i0x81lvaro
Scooter 0xf00x9d0x90ƒ0xf00x9d0x900xb20xf00x9d0x900xa50xf00x9d0x90š0xf00x9d0x900xa7`

I'd actually like to get the symbols €, ‡ etc in there.

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer escorting to a python one-liner, using `:py3do` (if you're on a older version of vim you might need `:pydo`)

```
" transforms 'samuel i<81>ngel' to 'samuel i\x81ngel
" Python variable `line` represents the input line
" Return value indicates what to transform the input line into
:py3do return ''.join([x if ord(x) < 128 else f'\\x{ord(x):02x}' for x in line])
```

Also it looks like you're opening the text file in the wrong encoding because usually when opened in the right encoding, text files do not contain unprintable raw characters.

(Actually I'm not quite sure what your requirements are, but with python it's quite easy to go the other way round, as you've got `str::printable` etc and you can even import some modules)